# $V=U\oplus W,T\in \text{End}(V), q\in \Bbb F[x], \text{ker}(q(T)) \subseteq W \Rightarrow U \subseteq \text{Im}(q(T))$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimension vector space over $\Bbb F$. Let  $T\in \text{End}(V)$,  $U,W$ T-invariant subspaces of $V$ s.t.  $V=U\oplus W$ $q\in \Bbb F[x]$ and $ \text{ker}(q(T)) \subseteq W$ then: $U \subseteq \text{Im}(q(T))$

So far I have concluded: if $U=0$ we are done. so let $0\neq u\in U.$ $ U \cap W = {0} \Rightarrow q(T)(u)\neq0$

Also, since U is T-invariant it is also $q(T)$-invariant and therefore we get: 
$\forall u\in U$ $ q(T)(u)\in U$

I am assuming whatever it is I am missing has to do with the fact the operator involved is a polynomial but can't figure out how to move on from here.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why is $U$ $T-$invariant?

Comment: Moreover, I think there is nothing related to the polynomial $q$ because nothing lost if you see $q(T)$ as a new action $T'$.

Comment: It is given U and W are T-Invariant (Sorry for the mess, I haven't mastered the whole MathJax thing yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $q(T)(U) \subseteq U$ and so $q(T)$ induces a linear transformation $S: U \to U$.

Now $\ker S = U \cap \ker q(T) \subseteq U \cap W = 0$.

So, $S$ is injective and thus surjective.

Therefore, $U=\text{Im}(S) \subseteq \text{Im}(q(T))$.

Comment: I don't think we need that $W$ is $T$-invariant.